# How do I modify a Sharepoint 2010 form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to modify what seems to be a form in sharepoint. I need to remove some options and add new ones. I see where I can modify a site by choosing Site actions in the top left hand corner of the site page. I have gone to the Library Tab (on the ribbon) -> Library Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Document Template -> Edit Template but when I click on Edit template, Infopath appears with no form in it, nothing to edit and no error message.

How can I find where the form resies and how can I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

try opening the library in SharePoint Designer. Look for template.xsl